# A great part of art

Tags: word-usage

Would a native speaker say "They are great parts of art", if I am talking about music and dance? And if I am talking about one thing, for example, photography can I say  "It's a great part of art"? Is  it  grammatically correct and natural?

Perhaps I should use "an art form" and "art forms" instead? Do native speakers prefer "art forms" and "an art form" instead of "a form of art" and "forms of art"?
For example, "It's a beautiful art form." Not "It's a beautiful form of art." Or "They are beautiful art forms." Instead of "They are beautiful forms of art."

Comment: “parts of art” is not something a native speaker would say. Depending on the intended message perhaps “forms of art” or “art forms” just “arts” might be better options.

Comment: I think the choices you are giving in your edit are equally fine and just a matter of taste or preference.

Comment: We sometimes say "great **works** of art" for individual pieces, and this can refer to music, literature, painting, sculpture etc. So you can say of a photograph "This is a (great) work of art." Aside: it does not have to be beautiful, but expressive.

Comment: Is "a part of art" also unnatural? Just like it's plural form? Do you mean "art forms" and "forms of art" "an art form" and "a form of art" are all correct?

Comment: Perhaps "art form" is a better generalisation. We don't say "parts of art".

Comment: I was wondering if you use art forms or form instead of form or forms of art. I mean the shorter version.

Comment: `form of art` is by far the more likely way you will hear it. Much like you will hear "state of the art" and not "art state"

Comment: @eps At least in my neck of the woods (Southeastern US), I'd say "art form" is more common than "form of art" in general conversation, though both are fine.  As chasly's answer below explains, however, there might be some subtle differences that could make "form of art" preferable in this particular case...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Photography is a fascinating art form.
2. Photography is a fascinating form of art.

On the face of it, these mean the same thing.

I personally detect a slight difference. Sentence (1) assumes the reader already knows that photography is an art form. It merely tells us that it is a *fascinating* one. Sentence (2) *informs*  us that photography is a form of art. It adds in passing that is fascinating.

Notice that this difference could be made explicit by emphasising certain words when reading or speaking the sentences, e.g.

Photography is a ***fascinating*** art form.

vs

Photography is a fascinating ***form of art***.

Let's see if others agree with this distinction.

Comment: It's much the same distinction with ***artwork / work of art***. So *The Mona Lisa is a work of art* sounds completely natural, but the "unqualified" form *The Mona Lisa is an artwork* seems more than a little "odd" (whereas the "qualified" form *The Mona Lisa is a unique artwork* is fine).

Comment: Art form just sounds like something a robot would say.  `This art form is nice to look at bbzzzzttt brrrrrrrrr`

Comment: I agree that both versions are fine and both have subtly different implications... to me, the difference is that "form of art" emphasizes that we're discussing a specific _type_ of art, a particular subset of all forms of artistic expression.  Unless verbal emphasis is used to the contrary, I'd interpret "art form" to refer generically to just any ol' form of art.